# UWP cannot connect to local SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, uwp

I'm creating a simple UWP application working together with my local DB server I set up with SQL Server Management Studio.

I can successfully set up a connection in the server explorer and run queries in the DB:

[image: SERVER EXPLORER]

However when I run the application I get an error when the connection is being established:

[image: CONNECTION ERROR]

*System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException HResult=0x80131904 Message=A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 25 - Connection string is not valid) Source=Core .Net SqlClient Data Provider*

I'm not sure if it's a problem with the connection string or what else it could be. I checked the firewall settings and everything seems to be fine. The SQL server settings also allow for remote connection.

Comment: On SO errors are preferred in text over images.

Comment: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
  HResult=0x80131904
  Message=A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 25 - Connection string is not valid)
  Source=Core .Net SqlClient Data Provider

Comment: [edit] into the question please.

Comment: Have you select the Enterprise Authentication, etc capability in manifest file? In general, maybe you could try to replace the server part with the actual SQL instance name (<machine name> or <machine name>\<instance name> for a named instance), if you use it, will the same issue occur? In addition, you could also refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/troubleshoot-connecting-to-the-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15) to troubleshoot.

Comment: Still no luck, followed all the steps of the document. I can connect to the DB with a simple command line app but not with my UWP app.

Comment: Do you enable TCP/IP for SQL Server and make sure that your SQL Server Browser service is running? Here is an [official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/sql-server-samples/tree/master/samples/databases/northwind-pubs) about how to use SQL database, if you use it, can it connect your database successfully?

Comment: It turned out that I hadn't restarted the service since enabling TCP/IP for SQL. I restarted the service and everything works fine now. Thank you

Comment: Glad you solved it, I have converted the comment to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Which SQL Server version is running?

Have you tried with the following connection string format?

```
Data Source=.\\MSSQLServer;Initial Catalog=PapaDario;Trusted_Connection=yes;
```

Comment: Hi, SQL Server version 18. Unfortunately your suggested connection string format throws the same error.

Comment: Another thing you may try is replacing the Windows authentication within a SQL Server auth. Simply create a new user under `Security -> Users`, assign him the `sa` priviledges (only for testing/dev purposes) and finally update the connection string replacing the `Trusted_Connection=yes` with `User Id=x; Password=y;`
If still not working, you can find [here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/) more options

Comment: Still no luck, I created a simple command line application to test the same piece of code and it works fine connecting to the DB. Is there something different I should be doing when creating a UWP app?

Comment: I don't know since I haven't worked on UWP for a while and I had always used Sql Lite. Anyway, have you looked at [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-access/sql-server-databases)?

Answer (score 0):

Before you connect to your database, some aspect of the SQL Server configuration needs to be changed. First, ensure that you've enabled **TCP/IP** for SQL Server. You can do that in the Computer Management console. Then make sure that your **SQL Server Browser service** is running.